# How can I retrieve an entire wide row from cassandra using ruby

Tags: ruby, nosql, cassandra

So I have some rows that are very large. Some are a few million columns wide. Each column is a JSON object.

Obviously the data is larger than the max_packet in thrift and all I get all sorts of crazyness when I try to retrieve the entire row. Question is, is there a more sane way to retrieve the data (using ruby). It's all TimeUUID data, and I'd like to be able to retrieve the entire row using batches of 100 or 1000 or so at a time. However, I can't figure out a way to do this. Most of the range operations are key based and not column based.

Oh also, if I just do a plain out get, I'll crash 2 nodes of my ring (RF=2). GC appears to thrash during all that and I get a Java Heap OOM error on crash.

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Most of the range operations are key based and not column based.

Not sure what interface you're using, but Cassandra's API supports a [`get_slice`](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API) method which accepts a `SliceRange` that can specify a range of column names to return. The [twitter ruby client](https://github.com/twitter/cassandra) offers `:start` and `:finish` options to `get` and `multi_get` that map to the slice range.

Comment: It seems that iterating over get_slice is going to do it for me. Probably in the long run, I'll need to adjust so my row isn't quite so long. I am using the twitter ruby client.